# Error in installing truffle in macOS

Tags: truffle

I am facing some issue in the installation of truffle. I used the command

```
 sudo npm install -g truffle
 /Users/vikas/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.2/bin/truffle ->
 /Users/vikas/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.2/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js
 truffle@4.1.13 added 81 packages in 14.406
```

Successfully added the packages but when I run command `truffle version`

or any another truffle command it gives

```
 -bash: /usr/local/bin/truffle: No such file or directory.
```

I am using macOS please someone help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Truffle executable is currently installed in `/Users/vikas/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.2/bin/truffle`.
For some system or npm reason I ignore, this executable isn't accessible from the `PATH`

You can either:

**- add a [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to your `/usr/local/bin/`**

```
$ sudo ln -sf /Users/vikas/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.2/bin/truffle /usr/local/bin/
```

**- add `/Users/vikas/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.2/bin/` to your path**

Edit `~/.bash_profile`. There will be a line that says something like `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin`.

Add `:/Users/vikas/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.2/bin/` to the end (be sure you have the colon)